# Find and replace excluding comments in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I've renamed a variable in my code, so I'm going through and replacing all the instances that used the variable as well. This would be a straightforward find and replace, but the original variable is a word that also happens to be in a number of my comments. That is, something like this:

```
//Old: var input = getUserInput();
var userinput = getUserInput();

input = parseInt(input, 1);
doSomething(input); //Does something with the user's input
doSomethingElse(input); //Does something else with the user's input
```

I want to replace the instances of `input` outside of the comments, so that I get this:

```
//Old: var input = getUserInput();
var userinput = getUserInput();

userinput = parseInt(userinput, 1);
doSomething(userinput); //Does something with the user's input
doSomethingElse(userinput); //Does something else with the user's input
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you also use the name of the variable in strings? and (2) Do you use `/* ... */` syntax, or just `//` for your comments?

Comment: BONUS QUESTION! (3) Do you ever use `//` or `/*` or `*/` inside a string?

Comment: @ParthianShot No, only `//`, and no.